# How to store Browser Console errors log in reports file?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation

I want to fetch browser(Chrome) console errors in my test reports. I am using Selenium with Ruby and for reports, I have used Report Builder. I want to get the reports in json format

Answer (score 1):

The below code will log the console messages from the browser, you can save that in a file.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
def test
  Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path= File.expand_path("C:\\chromedriver.exe")
  @browser = Watir::Browser.new:chrome
  @browser.window.maximize
  @browser.goto("http://3qilabs.com/how_to/check-for-javascript-errors-on-a-page-with-ruby-and-selenium-webdriver/")
  arr2 = @browser.driver.manage.logs
  puts arr2.get(:browser)

end
test()
```

**Update:**

As suggested in the comments, using the `watir` gem:

```
require 'watir'

b = Watir::Browser.new
b.goto "https://nytimes.com"
b.driver.manage.logs.get(:browser).each do |log|
  puts log
end
```

Comment: is correct, but I would tidy up the code: https://gist.github.com/samnissen/730be7b78fb9f3b4e2080a0515f60690 Most importantly, note the gem is called `watir` now.

Comment: hi, I need some modifications in the code. instead of just printing the error I want to display the test as fail. do you have any suggestions?